# How to process the csv file with 60000 rows and write in h2 database?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a csv file with 60000 lines. i like to read and process the file and write in h2 database.
The problem is ,it had only processed the first 1000 rows. How to overcome this problem ?

Comment: Please share your code to be able to help you. Are you setting the `maxItemCount` parameter on your item reader (which I guess of type `FlatFileItemReader`)? Are you checking the results in h2's web console? By default, the console shows only 1000 rows at a time, and you can load more data by looking at next pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.